# How to change the value of specific key which is multiple time duplicated in the JSON using node JS

Tags: json

I'm trying to construct a function which will replace the value based on the path user given as input argument. I have a complex JSON with some duplicated key and user will give path of the element and based on that path It needs to replace the value of the particular key (which is possibly duplicated):

**SampleJSON.json:**

```
  {
        "product": "delivery",
        "Merchant": {
            "payment_method": "GPay"
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "total": "100",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "details": {
                        "subtotal": "100",
                        "tax": "1",
                        "insurance": "0.1"
                    }
                },
                "description": "The payment transaction description",
                "custom": "JACKSON DISPUTERS SYSTEMS",
                "invoicenumber": "",
                "descriptor": "null",
                "itemlist": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "name": "COMPUTER",
                            "description": "BLACK",
                            "quantity": "1",
                            "price": "100",
                            "tax": "1",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
                    ],
                    "shippingaddress": {
                        "recipient_name": "JACKSON DISPUTERS SYSTEMS",
                        "line1": "XXXX",
                        "line2": "XXXX",
                        "city": "XXXX",
                        "country_code": "XX",
                        "postal_code": "XXXX",
                        "phone": "XXXXXX",
                        "state": "XXXXXX"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order."
        }
```

**User Input:**

```
arg1: product.transactions.currency,
arg2: EUR
```

I just need to traverse through the above path (arg1) and replace the value of currency as AUD (arg2).

If you noticed the currency element is available in two different places in the given JSON file but I just want to replace the currency which is under the transactions array that mentioned in the arg1, and not the other one.

I just created the below code so far and It will traverse through each and every element in the given JSON but not sure how to replace the value for the given key (arg1).

```
  const arg1 = "product.transactions.currency";
  const condition = arg1.toString().split(".");
  const arg2 = "EUR";
  const cond = false;

  function process(key,value) {
        if(key === condition[condition.length-1]) //condition[condition.length-1] return currency
        {
        cond = true;
        console.log(key + " : "+value);
        }
    }
    
    function traverse(o,func) {
        for (var i in o) {
            func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
            if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
                if(cond === false)
                {
                traverse(o[i],func);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    traverse(SampleJSON, process);
```

The above code print the first occurrence of the "Currency" element but I just want to print the element based on the arg1 which is given by user, and want to replace that value based on arg2.

is there any npm package available to achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. A specific property (given by the user input) will always be unique. So why the _"multiple time duplicated..."_ part?

Comment: _"Is there any npm package is available to achieve this?"_ - Asking for libraries or other off-site resources is off-topic

Comment: Actually User want to change the currency element which may occur multiple times in the SampleJSON file. but User interested to change the currency which is under transactions and not under items[]

Comment: Hence the "path" is `product.transactions.currency`

Comment: `product.transactions` is an array (and therefor `product.transactions.currency` doesn't exist). Should this change the `currency` of every object in that array? If not, how do you specify the exact element in the array?

Comment: Actually, the currency will not be duplicated inside the transaction array. But there may be possibilities that It will be under some other array. While I'm trying to traverse through the element tree not sure that I'm trying to get the right one instead of checking if(key === condition[condition.length-1])  this logical operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lodash `set` method to assign a value on a specific path in an object. First, run the below command to install the package:

```sh
yarn install lodash.set
```

**Usage**

```js
const set = require('lodash.set');

set(yourObject, 'product.transactions.currency', 'EUR');
```

Comment: Please search for duplicates (and close-vote as such) first.

Comment: I already went through the duplicate which is not solving my problem, and andreas thanks for sharing the links. And zeeshan Ahamad thank for sharing what I'm exactly looking for. You saved my time. Once again thanks much.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan literally all the duplicates suggested solve your issue